# Why is everything in my PST file showing up as a "draft"?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, migration, google-workspace, pst

I'm trying to move a client's email from Gmail to Google Apps Mail. Believe it or not, this is a very tedious process that doesn't have any good way from Google to do it. This client has over 91,000 emails to migrate and last night I was able to stump Google Apps support with it. They got us going on moving them over via POP3 but that wouldn't retain folder/label information and was dog slow (12 hours to move 1,000 emails) so that wouldn't work.

We happened across the idea of migrating all of the client's Gmail messages to an Outlook PST file and then using the Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Outlook utility (from Google) to migrate them. I used the [SysTools Gmail Backup](http://www.systoolsgroup.com/gmail-backup.html) program to do the backup from Gmail and it took ~13 hours but it finished.

Now I'm using GAMMO to try and import it but the emails I tried to move before pausing were showing up as drafts. I mounted the PST file in Outlook 2013 and sure enough, every single email in the file is a draft. Even the emails that were not sent by my client but rather to my client.

So my question is - is there any way to fix the PST file so that the emails won't all be "draft" status? And if not does anyone know the right way to migrate over 90,000 emails from Gmail to Google Apps that doesn't take forever or lose folder information?

(for what it's worth we tried just moving them with Outlook and there's just too many of them - even moving just a few thousand eventually kills Outlook)

Comment: Have you tried Outlook IMAP with GMail?

Comment: @snowdude yes, and I can't get it working. Namely the migration tools from Google don't work and there's too many emails to do it in Outlook itself (Outlook craps out). I have a support ticket with Google in progress right now, as well as with the company that made the PST export program. Both are stumped. My small business client has completely baffled a billion dollar corporation.

Comment: You could try a different IMAP client, like Thunderbird to see if that can at least pull the emails down? Getting it into Outlook from Thunderbird should be easier.

Comment: I would caution against using PST if keeping the email headers etc intact is important. Microsoft has a way of discarding message metadata and then inventing new message metadata out of thin air if you should ask for it back.

Comment: @tripleee A `.pst` file has no bearing on email headers, as it's simpy a local Outlook asynchronous database file, conversely an `.ost` file is an online Outlook synchronous database file, each housing contact, emails, folders, RSS feeds, calendars, etc.

Comment: @TomKidd You may want to try creating an `archive.pst` specifically for Gmail _(with `.ost` databases, you can't archive its data to an `archive.pst` used by another account)_, archiving all mail, which will move it from the `.ost` database to a `.pst` database. Once done, set up the GAM, import the `archive.pst`, and un-archive all mail via Outlook, which will move it from the `archive.pst` back to the new GAM `.ost` database. I've never tried this, so use Outlook's _Copy to Folder_ to copy ~10 emails to a new directory and use those 10 as a test to ensure it works correctly.